# resetting value of a local variable

Tags: linux, shell

I am using a local variable record in a for loop like

```
record=$(awk 'NF!=4 {print $0}' n20${i})
```

but everytime instead of taking a new value it appends last value to new value. How can I solve my problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I expect it to show the incomplete line in the second file but it appends the expected answer with the value of record from prevoius file

Comment: I don't think Awk is the problem. Could you post some lines of content and maybe some sample output?

Comment: Show more of your script. The problem is not in this line.

Comment: I want to copy last line of file n20${i} to file n20${i+1}, I don't know how to go to this second file as n20${i+1} doesn't work can you help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
record=$(awk 'NF!=4 {print $0}' n20$((i++)))
```

That will increment the value of `i` each time the line is executed.

Or if you just want `i+1` without changing the value of `i`:

```
record=$(awk 'NF!=4 {print $0}' n20$((i+1)))
```